# Definition of the Coefficients of the connection and the covariant derivative

Tags: differential-geometry

I am watching this general relativity course on youtube and they define the coefficients of the connection on the first line of this timestamp of the video:

https://youtu.be/X5TU0eNz5cU?t=1665

Notice that the $\Upsilon$ symbols represent elements of an arbitrary basis (not necessarily coordinate/holonomic).

My questions are two:

1-First in this course they get that the covariant derivative of a vector field in an arbitrary basis has a term contracting the *first* lower index of the coefficient of the connection with he vector field. This is opposite to what I see in most other places where they contract the second one, but it is true that in most other sources they work with a torsion free connection and in a coordinate basis for which the symbol is symmetric. Is the expression they obtain the correct one?

2-How does one get from the second step of the first line (right after the definition symbol) to the next step? I am not sure I can prove it or how to see it is consistent. I was wondering if anybody could help me out here. I can follow everything else in the course but this pesky bit :).

Thank you very much in advance!

Edit: In case the link doesn't work, I am referring to timestamp 27:45

Answer (score 1):

1. You're correct that the more usual conventional of the $\Gamma$'s would be to take $\nabla_{\Upsilon_b}\Upsilon_c = \Gamma^a_{\ bc}\Upsilon_a$. However it's just a convention, so as long as the lecturer is consistent, it shouldn't be a problem.
2. To go from the first step to the second: presumably $\Upsilon^a$ denotes the dual basis to $\Upsilon_a$, i.e. the set of 1-forms satisfying $\langle \Upsilon^a, \Upsilon_b\rangle = \delta^a_b$. Then since the vector fields $\Upsilon_a$ form a basis at each point, $\nabla_{\Upsilon_b}\Upsilon_c$ must be expressible as a linear combination of the $\Upsilon_a$, i.e.
   $$
   \nabla_{\Upsilon_c}\Upsilon_b = A^a_{\ cb}\Upsilon_a
   $$
   for some functions $A^a_{\ bc}$. Then apply the dual form $\Upsilon^d$ to both sides to yield
   $$
   \langle \Upsilon^d,\nabla_{\Upsilon_c}\Upsilon_b\rangle = A^a_{\ cb}\langle\Upsilon^d,\Upsilon_a\rangle\\
   \implies \Gamma^d_{\ bc} = A^a_{\ bc}\delta^d_a = A^d_{\ cb}
   $$
   giving the expression.